# Rails 6 - How to substitute a part of the routes URI pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

If user calls an URL ***application.com***, it redirects to ***application.com/account/1/sessions/new***.

I would like to substitute the redirect URL to ***application.com/sessions/new*** (host/account/:id -> host)

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get '/', to: 'dashboard#index'

  resources :accounts do
    resources :sessions
  end

end
```

**rails routes:**

```
new_account_session GET    /accounts/:account_id/sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

...
  #account has a column host to be identified if the user called URL host belongs to an existing account
  def get_account_id
    account_id = Account.find_by(host: request.host).id
  end

  def authorize
    if session[:user_id]
      redirect_to new_account_session_path(get_account_id)
      return
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove :sessions from inside :accounts

```
resources :accounts
resources :sessions
```

When you nest resources like that, you are basically saying that all routes to sessions should be linked to an account.